# How do I add strings of text to a Reportlab PDF table document?

Tags: python, reportlab

Below is a table I have created using the Reportlab library, specifically the SimpleDocTemplate from reportlab.platypus:

```
# Data for this example
data = [
    ['Animal', 'Name', 'Color'],
    ['Dog', 'Fido', 'Brown'],
    ['Cat', 'Mittens', 'Black'],
    ['Fish', 'Bubbles', 'Orange']
]

fileName = 'pdfTable.pdf'

# Using a template to make the PDF
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate # With this, our table will automatically be centered in the document
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

pdf = SimpleDocTemplate (
    fileName,
    pagesize=letter
)

# Import table functionality and create table
from reportlab.platypus import Table
table = Table(data)

# Add style
from reportlab.platypus import TableStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors

style = TableStyle([
    ('BACKGROUND', (0,0), (3,0), colors.green),
    ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (-1,0), colors.whitesmoke), # The negative one means "go to the last element"
    
    ('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
    
    ('FONTNAME', (0,0), (-1,0), 'Courier-Bold'),
    ('FONTSIZE', (0,0), (-1,0), 14),
    
    ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0,0), (-1,0), 12), # 12 = 12 pixels
    
    ('BACKGROUND', (0,1), (-1,-1), colors.beige), # Background for the rest of the table (excluding the title row)
])
table.setStyle(style)

elems = []
elems.append(table)

pdf.build(elems)
```

Which produces the following table in a PDF:

[image]

I want to add strings of text in other places of the document, outside of the table. Normally, I would use "canvas" from reportlab.pdfgen:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
pdf = canvas.Canvas('myFile.pdf')
pdf.drawCentredString(300, 770, 'Title')
```

But this doesn't work with SimpleDocTemplate, and I believe it just creates a new document. How do I create independent text strings in conjunction with a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reportlab.platypus.SimpleDocTemplate` creates document from flowables. Flowable is a block of content that occupy some vertical space. If you want title before you table, just create paragraph with title style and put it in list before table, if you want to add text after the table, put it after. If you want arbitrary placed text create a function and pass it to `SimpleDocTemplate.build` as `onFirstPage` argument.

```py
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import cm

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

flowables = [
    Paragraph('Title', styles['Title']),
    table,
    Spacer(1 * cm, 1 * cm),
    Paragraph('text after spacer')
]

def onFirstPage(canvas, document):
    canvas.drawCentredString(100, 100, 'Text drawn with onFirstPage')

pdf.build(flowables, onFirstPage=onFirstPage)
```